# Visual Basic equivalent to file get contents?

Tags: php, vb.net

Is there a function in Visual Basic that does the same thing as file_get_contents in PHP.
I'm a PHP programmer, and I want to write a few scripts to download some data from an API I'm using.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet3040.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.Net (I'm assuming that's what you're looking for), I think you'd want to look at the `WebClient.DownloadFile` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) if the file you want is on the web.  If it's a local file you could use...

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
```

I'm not familiar with PHP's file_get_contents but if it's asynch you can call `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync`

Comment: Will `ReadAllText()` convert a binary file's contents into an ASCII string that matches what `file_get_contents()` would produce?